# Nil while unwrapping an optional that actually has a value

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I'm getting a very weird error, while unwrapping an optional. When I print the value, I can actually see it but yet, it crashes and it says:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here's the code (`fetchPost()` is called in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
func fetchPost() {
    Api.Posts.observePostIncludingImages(withId: postId) { (post, photosStringArray) in

        self.isLiked(postId: post.id!, completion: { boolValue in
            Api.Posts.fetchCount(postId: post.id!, completion: { totalCount in
                post.isLiked = boolValue

                self.photosArrayString = photosStringArray
                print(photosStringArray) // prints the actual image string
                self.setScrollView()

            })
        })
    }
}

func setScrollView() {
    for  i in stride(from: 0, to: photosArrayString.count, by: 1) {
        var frame = CGRect.zero
        frame.origin.x = self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size = self.galleryScrollView.frame.size
        galleryScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        let newUIImageView = UIImageView()
        print(photosArrayString[i]) // Prints the value again
        let myImage = UIImage(named: photosArrayString[i])! // CRASHES! i = 0 (first item in the array)

        avgBackgroundColorsOfImage.append(myImage.averageColor!)

        newUIImageView.image = myImage
        newUIImageView.frame =  frame

        newUIImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

        newUIImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.photosArrayString[i]), completed: nil)


        galleryScrollView.backgroundColor = avgBackgroundColorsOfImage[i]
        galleryScrollView.addSubview(newUIImageView)

        self.galleryScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(photosArrayString.count),
                                                    height: self.galleryScrollView.frame.size.height)
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changePage), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are unwrapping is the optional `UIImage` you just created. Whatever string is being held in the array is a valid string. It is not, however, the name of a valid image in your asset catalog. Note the error is about "unwrapping a nil value", not "array out of bounds" - these are different things.

The [docs on this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) show how it's an optional init that returns "the image object for the specified file, or nil if the method could not find the specified image."

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you

Comment: Will do, but there's a waiting time, it says 2 min right now. I will accept it :)